# Custom HtmlHelper returns encoded html

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

Im doing a custom htmlhelper, its purpose is to build a `ul`, problem is that it returns `encoded html` and i cant get around it. I tried to use `html.raw()` with no success. Ideas?

HtmlHelper

```
public static MvcHtmlString TopMenu(this HtmlHelper helper, IEnumerable<string> names)
{
    var ulTag = new TagBuilder("ul");

    foreach (var name in names)
    {
        var liTag = new TagBuilder("li");

        liTag.SetInnerText(string.Format("<img src='{0}' alt='alt' />{1}", name, name));
        ulTag.InnerHtml += liTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
    }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(ulTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

My view

```
@Html.Raw(Html.TopMenu(CodeTesting.Models.NamesList.Names(20)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`liTag.SetInnerText()` escapes the **text** that you pass it.
You want to set `liTag.InnerHtml`.

Also, you need to HTML-escape `name`.

Comment: Not sure i follow you here, could you show with an example? thanks

Comment: What Name i need to html-escape? sorry but i never used that before so not sure where to either.

Comment: Whenever you insert text into HTML source, you need to escape it to prevent the text from being parsed as HTML.

Comment: So `liTag.SetInnerText(string.Format("<img src='{0}' alt='alt' />{1}", helper.AttributeEncode(name), helper.AttributeEncode(name)));`?

Comment: Exactly.  Note that you can write `{0}` twice.